# How can define default locale ? Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I try to config my default locale to fr........ but it dont work.

In my application.rb :

```
config.load_defaults 5.1
config.i18n.locale = :fr
config.i18n.default_locale = :fr
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
```

but I always have my app with params "locale"=>"en" where is the mistake ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `default_locale` as you have, and also prsent available locales:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :fr
I18n.available_locales = [:fr]
```

in your application.rb

Comment: It don't work. 

I try with :
I18n.available_locales = [:fr, :en]
config.i18n.available_locales = [:fr, :en]

But locale is always in "en"

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: I found where is the problem :

I'm using route translator and index page get locale as en (I don't no why). May be I must add an attribute "locale" to my routes, but I don't know how can I do...

      `localized do
        root to: 'ways#index'
        resources :ways, only:[:index, :show] ....`